# How to rename files with part of folder name?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have files as below:

> H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir1 **[60]19**\[0]--[30]15 **[60]--**[65]--[999]abc.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir200\ssdir5 **[60]22**\[0]20[30]15 **[60]--**[65]22[999]abcd.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir20 **[60]218**\[0]--[30]15 **[60]--**[65]100[999]21ade.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir33 **[60]335**\[0]--[30]15 **[60]--**[65]31[999]2ade.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir5 **[60]26**\[0]--[30]15 **[60]--**[65]--[999]1abc4.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir8000 **[60]525**\[0]--[30]15 **[60]--**[65]--[999]abc4.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir7 **[61]12**\[0]--[30]15 **[61]--**[65]--[999]abc5.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir33 **[61]25**\[0]--[30]15 **[61]--**[65]--[999]ffc5.jpg

Which I want to rename with a batch in:

> H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir1[60]19\[0]--[30]15 **[60]19**[65]--[999]abc.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir200\ssdir5 [60]22\[0]20[30]15 **[60]22**[65]22[999]abcd.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir20 [60]218\[0]--[30]15 **[60]218**[65]--[999]21ade.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir33 [60]335\[0]--[30]15 **[60]335**[65]31[999]2ade.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir5 [60]26\[0]--[30]15 **[60]26**[65]--[999]1abc4.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir8000 [60]525\[0]--[30]15 **[60]525** [65]--[999]abc4.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir7 [61]12\[0]--[30]15 **[61]12**[65]--[999]abc5.jpg
>   H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir33 [61]25\[0]--[30]15 **[61]25**[65]--[999]ffc5.jpg

The last part of the folder name, starting with `[`, must become the string which will replace the string with which the same number begins in the new file name.

Thus replacing **[60]--** with **[60]19** in the first example.

The length of paths, strings and file names are variable.

I know the solution is using `tokens` and `delims`, but I didn't find out how to get the right strings in all cases.

---

**EDIT 1**:

I have this so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "sourcedir=H:\1\Pictures\some\dir\sdir1 [60]19"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (    
'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
) DO (

set newstr=%sourcedir:~-2,2%  
ren "%%a" ????"(%newstr%)"????????????????????????????????
)
```

Issues I have:

1. The files are renamed, but have `()` instead of `19`.
2. The path is hard coded instead of being a variable.
   (H:\1\Pictures` + variable for some\dir\sdir1 [60]19, some2\dir\sdir5 [60]26...)
3. In `set newstr=%sourcedir:~-2,2%` I set fixed the last 2 positions of the path name. It could be necessary to have 3 positions, e.g. [60]225.
4. In the rename command I use ??? instead of variables, not being a solution to use with a variable position or length for the elements.

---

**EDIT 2**:

I resolved the first issue. `set newstr=%sourcedir:~-2,2%` didn't work.

So I changed

```
ren "%%a" ????"(%newstr%)"????????????????????????????????
```

to

```
ren "%%a" ????"%sourcedir:~-2,2%"????????????????????????????????.
```

But how to know that there have to be 2 or 3 digits in `%sourcedir%`?

Comment: [This link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ben/2007/03/09/path-manipulation-in-a-batch-file/) could help

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "ListFile=%TEMP%\FilesNotRenamed.tmp"
del "%ListFile%" 2>nul
set "FileCount=0"

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B /S "H:\1\PICTURES\*.jpg" 2^>nul') do (

    set "FileName=%%~nxA"
    set "FilePath=%%~dpA"
    set "FilePath=!FilePath:~0,-1!"

    for /F "delims=" %%B in ("!FilePath!") do (
        for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]" %%C in ("%%~nxB") do (

            set "FileName=!FileName:[%%C]--=[%%C]%%D!"
            if not exist "%%~dpA!FileName!" (
                ren "%%A" "!FileName!"
            ) else if not "%%~nxA" == "!FileName!" (
                set /A FileCount+=1
                echo %%A>>"%ListFile%"
            )

        )
    )
)

if exist "%ListFile%" (
    set "PluralS=s"
    if %FileCount% == 1 set "PluralS="
    echo The following %FileCount% file!PluralS! could not be renamed because a
    echo file with target name exists already in same directory:
    echo/
    type "%ListFile%"
    del "%ListFile%"
    echo/
    pause
)

endlocal
```

The most outer **FOR** runs command **DIR** which outputs because of `/B` (bare format) and `/S` (search also recursive in all subdirectories) all names of *.jpg files with full path never enclosed in double quotes found in directory `H:\1\PICTURES` and all its subdirectories ignoring directories ending by chance also with `.jpg` (very unlikely but who knows).

**DIR** outputs for the example:

```
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir5 [60]26\[0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]--[999]1abc4.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir1 [60]19\[0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]--[999]abc.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir8000 [60]525\[0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]--[999]abc4.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir20 [60]218\[0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]100[999]21ade.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir33 [60]335\[0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]31[999]2ade.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some\dir\sdir200\ssdir5 [60]22\[0]20[30]15 [60]--[65]22[999]abcd.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir7 [61]12\[0]--[30]15 [61]--[65]--[999]abc5.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir33 [61]25\[0]--[30]15 [61]--[65]--[999]ffc5.jpg
H:\1\PICTURES\some2\dir\sdir33 [61]25\[0]--[30]15 [61]25[65]--[999]ffc5.jpg
```

`2^>nul` results in redirecting the error message output by **DIR** to **STDERR** to the device **NUL** to suppress it if no  *.jpg file could be found at all. The character `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be interpreted as redirection operator on execution of command **DIR** and not already on parsing **FOR** command line which would result in an exit of batch execution because of a syntax error.

This list of file names is next processed line by line by the most outer **FOR** whereby each file name with path is assigned to loop variable `A`. The by default done splitting of the string on spaces/tabs is disabled by `delims=`.

The file name with file extension of current file is assigned to environment variable `FileName` and the file path is assigned to environment variable `FilePath`.

Next the backslash at end of the file path is removed from file path which is important for next **FOR**.

Environment variables defined/modified within a command block starting with first `(` and ending with matching `)` must be referenced in same command block using delayed expansion because Windows command processor replaces all `%variable%` by the value of the environment variable already on parsing the entire command block before executing it the first time. This explains usage of `!FileName!` and `!FilePath!` and last also `!PluralS!` instead of `%FileName%` and `%FilePath%` and `%PluralS%` in batch code above.

The name of the folder is needed next in which the current file is stored. The directory name is get using one more **FOR** which parses the file path NOT ending with a backslash. The string after last backslash in `FilePath` is referenced with `%%~nxB` ... file name and file extension which is here the directory name as the string parsed is a file path ending with a folder name and not with a file name.

In outer words `%%~nxB` is for the example files:

```
sdir5 [60]26
sdir1 [60]19
sdir8000 [60]525
sdir20 [60]218
sdir33 [60]335
ssdir5 [60]22
sdir7 [61]12
sdir33 [61]25
sdir33 [61]25
```

The most inner **FOR** is used to get the number within the square brackets and the number after the square brackets. It splits the folder name up into strings using `[` and `]` as delimiters.

For this task the first string before first `[` is not of interest. Therefore with `tokens=2` the second string within the square brackets is assigned to loop variable `C`. The rest of the folder name after `]` is not split up further and is assigned to next loop variable which is according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) loop variable `D` specified with `*` after `tokens=2`.

For the examples files `%%C` (left number) and `%%D` (right number) are:

```
60   26
60   19
60   525
60   218
60   335
60   22
61   12
61   25
61   25
```

The first command in most inner **FOR** loop replaces **ALL** (and hopefully on all file names always only one) `[`*first number*`]--` by `[`*first number*`]`*second number* in current file name.

Then it is checked if a file with new name does not already exist before doing the file rename on which the file to rename is specified with full path and new file name without path.

There are two possibilities in case of file with new name already exists:

1. The current file was renamed already before. This can be detected if new file name is identical to name of file to rename. Nothing is done in this case.
2. There is another file in directory of file to rename which has the new file name. In this case the file to rename with path is recorded in a temporary file and a file counter is increased by 1.

After finishing the most outer **FOR** a check is made if the temporary file is created at all. In this case at least 1 file could not be renamed because there is already a file with new name in same directory. The list of not renamed files is output with halting batch execution until a key is pressed.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `type /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: But when I launch the script, the Dosbox appears & disappears immediately, without renaming any files. It seems like the set

Comment: I did what was suggested: I placed the file under C:, opened a command prompt window and ran the batch file by entering its name with full path enclosed in double quotes. A dosbox opened, without anything written in it and froze.

Comment: This batch file does not start a new command process. So by having this batch code saved into ANSI file `C:\Temp\RenameFiles.bat` and run from within opened command prompt window `"C:\Temp\RenameFiles.bat"` you should see any error message output if not suppressed like done with `2>nul` and `2^>nul`. Change first line to `@echo ON` before saving the batch file and running it to see which lines are processed on execution of the batch file. And temporarily remove all `2>nul` and `2^>nul` to see all error messages, too.

Comment: I think the problem are the SET commands. When I ask  in the script 'echo %FileName%' (after 'SET  "FileName=%%~nxA"'), the system returns nihil. When I then ask echo '%%~nxA', the system does return the filename (e.g. [0]--[30]15 [60]--[65]--[999]abc.jpg).

Comment: You can't use `%FileName%` in a command block starting with `(` and ending with a matching `)` if in same command block the environment variable is defined or modified as done here. That's the reason why delayed expansion is enabled at top of the batch script and used by referencing environment variable `FileName` with `!FileName!`. Please run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output help pages as I posted. The help explains delayed expansion on an __IF__ and a __FOR__ command block example. Thousands of questions on SO related to batch file are about delayed expansion.

Comment: Note: I tested the batch file before posting it as you can see with all the additional output I posted using your directory structure and your files. So I'm 100% sure that the batch file as posted works for the directories and files in your example. If your directory structure or file names are different to what you have posted, edit your question. Or you really have to find out by yourself how to adapt the batch code for your real directory structure and your real file names.